# Data attribute is returning undefined in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

This was working for me before but stopped working. I am trying grab the data attribute so that I can add to cart via AJAX.

UPDATE: My goal is to get the data from the data-variant-id attribute so that I can add to cart via Shopify's AJAX API. Previously, I had a button that said ADD TO CART and that worked well. All of a sudden, the button stopped working when I added an icon tag.

This is the snippet:

```js
// Fake Shopify
const Shopify = {
  addItem (id, qty, cb) {
    console.log("Shopify.addItem - id: %s, qty: %i", id, qty)
    setTimeout(cb, 200)
  }
}

const refreshCart = () => console.log("refreshCart")

$('[data-variant-id]').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = e.target
    var variantId = button.dataset.variantId

    console.log('variantId', variantId);

    // Add Item to cart
    Shopify.addItem(variantId, 1, function() {

      // Now its added. lets refresh the cart drawer
      refreshCart();

      // Now its refreshed. Lets open the drawer
      $('[data-drawer-trigger]')[0].click();
    })
  })
})
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css");
[data-drawer-trigger] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-variant-id="40173189300410" value="Add to Cart" class="btn-icon"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>

<button data-drawer-trigger>Drawer Trigger Button</button>
```

Comment: How can we know why it's stop working ? You just added html, js who is already working please provide more details

Comment: I have dylsexia can you let me know what other information you need?

Comment: I edited your post based on assuming you used `jquery 3.0`, then it seems your codes work fine. if the version is not correct, please update the jquery version inside the snippet.

Comment: So I have updated my request. After testing I found that if I put an icon within the button then the code doesn't work

Comment: @RyanPerez also, I think your icon classes should be `fas fa-shopping-cart`, **not** `far fa-shopping-cart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var button = e.target
> ```

This is your problem.

When you click on the button, you're most likely actually clicking on the `<i>` which is the element identified by `e.target`.

The event bubbles up to the button which triggers your event handler but then your `<i>` does not have any `data-*` attributes so `button.dataset.variantId` is `undefined`.

The simple solution is to use jQuery's `this` binding in the event handler which binds to the [event currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (the element you added the handler on). You also don't need `.each()`

```js
$('button[data-variant-id]').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const variantId = this.dataset.variantId // note `this`

  console.log('variantId', variantId);

  // Add Item to cart
  Shopify.addItem(variantId, 1, function() {

    // Now its added. lets refresh the cart drawer
    refreshCart();

    // Now it's refreshed. Lets open the drawer
    $('[data-drawer-trigger]').eq(0).click(); // using `.eq(0)` is safer
  })
})
```

---

Also, your icon should be

```html
<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
```

Note the `fas` class name, *not* `far`.